# Permutation function on $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

I'm curious about whether the function $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $\varphi(x)=x^3$ defines a permutation iff $p=5\pmod{6}$ (for $p\geq5$ of course). I have some evidence about it but it seems harder than I expected, I hope I'm not missing something important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^3=0$ if and only if $x=0$, the question boils down to determining for which $p$ the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

And because $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$, $x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism if and only if $p-1$ and $3$ are coprime. Finally, if $p\geq 5$ is prime then either $p\equiv 1$ (mod $6$) or $p\equiv 5$ (mod $6$), and so $x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism precisely when $p\equiv 5$ (mod $6$).

Comment: Why does $\varphi$ is an automorphism if and only if $p−1$ and $3$ are coprime?

Comment: If $3$ divides $p-1$ then $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ has an element $x$ of order $3$, so $x\neq 1$ and $x^3=1$. On the other hand, if $3$ and $p-1$ are coprime then there are integers $r$ and $s$ such that $3r+(p-1)s=1$, and so if $x^3=1$ then $x=x^{3r+(p-1)s}=x^{3r}x^{(p-1)s}=1$. So in this case $x\mapsto x^3$ is injective, hence also surjective.